# ASP Net Core HTTPS Compression Vulnerabilities - BREACH & CRIME

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application.
Server - IIS and Kestrel (We are going to docker soon, so it will be Kestrel server)
The application(service) is a plain API.
This API(service) is responsible for authentication, data processing.
So basically we send this data to the Browser(client)

Our SEO + Devops said that we need to improve API layer performance.
I went to the MSDN page and found [Response compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-3.1#response-compression-1)
So I added the HTTP and HTTPS compression. Then I scroll down the page and found [vulnerabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-3.1#compression-with-secure-protocol-1) when using compression.
It says that if I use HTTPS compression for dynamically generated pages then it could cause a vulnerability such as BREACH & CRIME.

So basically I want to ask - Is this a vulnerability I have to be careful of?
Should I implement some workaround if this is still a valid vulnerability for ASP.NET Core 3.1?
Is it different for IIS and Kestrel?

P.s.
Thank everyone for the help.

Comment: Have you concluded that it's the transportation of the data that is the issue here, and not the generation of it? If you're just grasping at "stuff that could potentially help" then I would first profile your application to ensure you're fixing the right issue. I'm commenting on your choice of optimization. I have no idea about those potential vulnerabilities.

Comment: you should take a look here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20406/is-http-compression-safe

Comment: I think only the body gets compressed by the browser these days... so anything in the header should be safe.  I would make a post over at securityexchange to be sure.  I believe "Breach" is already prevented by using anti-forgery tokens.  (It's pretty worrying that the 3.1-core page lists the vulnerabilities though... that can't be very old.. maybe a year or two?)

Comment: CVE: https://www.cve.org/CVERecord?id=CVE-2012-4929  It says it's a TLS1.2 vulnerability...  I don't think any versions of IIS support TLS1.3 yet.  So it's really whether the browsers fixed their end...

Comment: I agree with @pcalkins and I think ASP.NET Core is sensitive to BREACH attacks but not to CRIME attacks: It doesn't seem to enable SSL compression... So the rule might be not to put sensitive data in the body of a compressed dynamic response. (For me the headers are safe because not compressed)
see: [CRIME - How to beat the BEAST successor?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/19914/288752)